# Best way to Windows application development using C# + WPF + MVVC + prism 4?

Tags: c#, mvvm, prism, projects-and-solutions

I am little bit new in **.Net + C# + WPF + MVVC + prism 4**.

I am going to create one windows application using **C# and WPF.**

I think it's good to using **MVVM + prism 4.**

But be-four start to working, i want to know few think

> 1. Which is **Best Project Solution Structure for C# + WPF + MVVC +
>      prism 4**. Can give some reference for this.
> 2. Which is Best way to **create Project Solution Structure.**
> 3. Which is Best Way for **Exception Handling**
> 4. If any one know LinQ, **is LinQ suitable with WPF + MVVC + prism 4.**
>      Any LinQ extended library which help for development.
> 5. Any **Existing or 3'rd party library** which help for **development** like
>      Microsoft Enterprise Library
> 6. Any suggestions for different **Tool,Framework,Design Patterns.**
>      ...etc
> 7. Any **Reference/Help site** links

**Thanks In Advance**

Comment: This is a very broad question (in fact 7 questions). What research have you done so far? What have you found out yourself?

Comment: This would probably also be more suitable on programmers.stackoverflow.com...

Comment: Sorry, I understand the desire to ask questions like this, but they aren't acceptable here for the reasons explained below.  Also, asking multiple questions within a question is frowned upon.  There are plenty of questions here already that cover a lot of what you're asking.  I do daily what you are setting out to do, so will give you some hints 1) there is no best, but simple and clean are the goals to strive for 2) with care 3) at the last responsible moment 4) just linq to objects, sorry 5) check wpf on nuget 6) nope 7) search here

Comment: @J.Steen: And, no, it wouldn't.  It is WAY too broad.  Perhaps one or two of the questions, if they are reworded so as to be answerable without spawning debate or speculation.

Comment: @Will, I was under the impression programmers -was- a site for debate and speculation, as long as it was clear it was a subjective question, and quite possibly marked as community wiki. =)

Comment: @J.Steen: Whatever you do, don't say that to a Programmers regular/mod.  I'm afraid you wouldn't survive.  Check out their faq, and if you're brave, check their meta.

Comment: @Will, I got that impression from the FAQ, actually, but the meta does look scary, yes... =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will suggest the path that I followed.

Download the Prism, go through the samples (Quickstarts in the zip file) and also read the documentation (Prism4.chm). Once you graduate from the samples, have a look at the "StockTrader RI" that also comes with prism itself.

Once you are settled a little bit, you can start working on the structure of solutions that suits the best for you.

Vijay